# skipping recursion

Tags: recursion

The first line is a number, int x. The following m lines contain letters.  After m lines, you read in a number, int y.

The goal is to find the soluiton number, int y, from recursion of 1 letter from each line.

The problem states that there’s a much faster solution which avoids going through each possible password. That is where my question is. How can this be done? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is somehow comon sense on stackoverlow not just to write code for homework question, as it keeps you from learning. Yo should show, what you got so far and explain, where you got stuck.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I'm of the opinion that in many cases people don't know where to start.  A few hints don't hurt, especially if they get people thinking in the right direction

Comment: @nirk, sure. I know the brain pain recursion can cause. But still op should show some effort

Comment: This sort of homework isn't hard enough to warrant help with no effort, this isn't a hard maths question.

Comment: I don't understand the example input/output: if we should choose one letter from each line - how can `r` be bigger than 3 ? or did you mean that `r` is the number of elements in that output list which then should be something like: `axd, axm, axn,...` (sorted alphabetically)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not that complicated. You can count the number of letters in the m lines. Then you calculate a value for every line of letters, that specifies how many possible solutions are skipped, if one letter in the referenced line is skipped. Visualized:

```
abc -> 3 letters
xy -> 2 letters
dmnr -> 4 letters
```

if you skip from the n-th letter to the n+1-th letter in the "abc" line, you skip as many possible solutions as the product of the length of every following line says. so you skip 2*4 solutions -> `8 solutions`.

repeat this step for xy -> `4 solutions` skipped.

the last line skips alwasy `1 solution`, because it is the recursion path itself.

so now you know, how many solutions you skip, if you skip to some specific letter. the last thing is simple. you start with 1 and add the calculated value of each line to the number, until it reaches exactly r.

means in c++:

```
int v = 1, r=10;
int i1=0, i2=0, i3=0;

while (v<=r-8) {
  i1++;
  v+=8;
}
while (v<=r-4) {
  i2++;
  v+=4;
}
while (v<=r-1) {
  i3++;
  v++;
}
```

now i1 is the index of the letter you need to use from the "abc" line, i2 is the index of the letter from "xy" and i3 from "dmnr" :) thats all. the algorithm should end with i1=1, i2=0, i3=1 -> "b" + "x" + "m"

I hope this helps. It removes the recursion, but that's no problem, is it? ;)